# ssh safe to add private key to authorized_keys

Tags: ssh

Can someone confirm if it's safe to add a private key (`.pem`) to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on a computer that will be connecting to a remote server (where the public key will be). I plan on using `cat private-key.pem >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to add it. I've already changed the permissions on authorized_keys using `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

I've been looking the last hour and all I can see are references to the public key on the remote server. Struggling to find much relevant info on whether the above is safe or not.

I want to do the above so I can add `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `~/.ssh/config` to allow me connect quickly.

Sorry if this is obvious but it's been a while since I've used SSH. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 3):

No. It is not. To the authorized keys, you should put public key!

You can generate public key from private key using `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f private-key.pem > public-key.pub
```

Comment: So I add the public key to 'authorized_keys' on the client computer as well as the server?

Comment: No. Only on the server. Your client key will be authorized to access the server (from the name of the file).

Comment: The public key is in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server. When I delete the file `authorized_keys` on the client computer then I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` message when I try to SSH to the server. Should I have something else in `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: Yes. The `IdentityFile /path/to/private-key.pem`

Comment: Right that works perfect thanks. Can I ask why adding it to `authorized_keys` on the client is not safe? Does that file get shown to servers?

Comment: The purpose of `authorized_keys` is not to hold any arbitrary key you want to put there; it stores *public keys* that you can use to log in. That is, if you have the matching private key on *other* end, `sshd` will allow you to log in.

Comment: Adding a private key there is not safe.